# How do I remove deleted Python environments in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

When I'm creating a new project in PyCharm, I can see some environments I created for old projects that have been deleted:

[image: New Project]

but I can't find a way to delete these entries. Where are they? How do I delete them?

I tried going to "Python Interpreters" following https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#removing_interpreter but they are just not there:

[image: Settings]

[image: Python interpreters]

Comment: Please check the following link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#removing_interpreter Was it useful?

Comment: @LazyOne unfortunately it didn't. The interpreters are just not there. I updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Interpreters list from the `New Project` dialogue **has a different entry point** from the project specific list. Go to `File` `>` `New Projects Setup` `>` `Settings for New Projects` (instead of going to `File` `>` `Settings` as usual):

[image: New projects setup]

Going through the other entry point you can already notice the `Python Interpreter` item in the sidebar is slightly different visually from if you had gone the other route. From there on the renaming dialogues are the same as usual but the lists are different. Continue to `Python Interpreter` `>` `Show All...` at the bottom of the drop down list:

[image: Show all]